# C/CUDA Program Output

Tags: c++, c, cuda

The following is a CUDA programming example which is basically C but with NVidia CUDA functions within. I've been trying to interpret this code example and figure out what it is trying to do. My question is this the program compiles just fine, but what arguments does it take? For example this CUDA program is being run in a linux emulator however upon running ./program it returns:

Usage: ./program number
Segmentation fault

What are the programs input arguments. Thank you.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#define N 100000

__host__ void saxpy_host(int length, float alpha, float * x, float * y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    y[i] = alpha*x[i] + y[i];
}

__global__ void saxpy (int length, float alpha, float * x, float * y)
{
   int i;
   i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   if (i < length) y[i] = alpha*x[i]+y[i];
   __syncthreads();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

if (argc != 2) { 
  printf("Usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
  return -1;
}

int N = atoi(argv[1]);

// host data
float alpha = 0.5;
float x[N], xback[N];
float y[N], yback[N];

int size;
int i;
int blocks;

// determining size 
size = sizeof(float)*N;


// device data
float * dxp, * dyp;


// fill host data
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   x[i] = (float) (rand () % 128);
   y[i] = (float) (rand () % 256);
}


// Allocating and Moving data to device
cudaMalloc((void**) &dxp, size);
cudaMalloc((void**) &dyp, size);
cudaMemcpy (dxp, x, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy (dyp, y, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// size of thread blocks
blocks = (N + 31)/32;
saxpy <<< blocks, 32 >>> (N, alpha, dxp, dyp);

// bring back data
cudaMemcpy (xback, dxp, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
cudaMemcpy (yback, dyp, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

// Calculating host SAXPY
saxpy_host (N, alpha, (float *) &x, (float *) &y);

// checking computation on host matches computation on GPU
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  assert (yback[i] == y[i]) ;
  //printf ("%i %f %f \n", i, yback[i], y[i]);
}


// free device data
cudaFree(dxp); cudaFree(dyp);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int N = atoi(argv[1]);
```

The program takes a single integer as a command line argument. (Try calling it as `./program 5`, for example.)

It then calculates a SAXPY (An old term originating from early BLAS implementations, but it stuck. It means "single (precision, aka float) real alpha x plus y".) with vectors of dimension `N`.

Comment: Any idea what int value would be. Placing a value of 100000 returns an error of: "" int main(int, char**): Assertion 'yback[i] == y[i]' failed. Aborted "" a really big number causes the error "" Segmentation Fault ""

Comment: Does it run for small values - `5` or `32`, maybe?

Comment: The program seems to run fine for me on a real GPU, I tried arguments of 5, 100, and 1000.  So most likely the problem is with your emulator.  Note that if the program is happy and computes a successfull result, it provides no output whatsoever.  If I uncomment the final printf, I get sensible-looking results for both GPU and CPU (they match, obviously).  So probably your emulator is suspect.  That final assertion failure you are reporting means that the calculation created an incorrect result that did not match the CPU side.  Again - your emulator is suspect.

Comment: Would you mind uploading the output data please? I had to use this emulator because of a lack of an NVidia GPU!

Comment: Sample output is [here](http://pastebin.com/Q7yRe0sJ).  If you simply comment out the final `assert` and uncomment the final `printf`, you should be able to run it even if your emulator doesn't produce the proper result, and see the results that are computed between CPU and emulator (they won't match, presumably).

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer given by us2012, can you please accept it?   The input argument becomes the length of the vectors that are filled with random values and then passed to the saxpy operations -- comparing host and device computations.